# Can PHP mess up a redirect? Is this possible?

Tags: php, security

**Scenario 1:**

```
<?php
header('Location: accessdenied');
//code to delete your entire database below
?>
```

Scenario 2:

```
<?php
header('Location: accessdenied');
die();
//code to delete your entire database below
?>
```

Hypothetically I was wondering if it was possible for a header to fail?

Let's say you had some code below that you never wanted to be executed and you left out a die(); would it be possible in any way for the code in scenario 1 to be executed.

Scenario 2 I know for a fact that the code below would never be executed.

But my question is, does the same hold true for scenario 1?

**Thanks :)**

P.S. I am aware that there is very little scenarios where this would happpen (As you could use if statements instead etc, but hypothetically I want to know if a header can not work and then cause the code below to execute?

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Comment: The code in scenario 1 will always be executed. A call to `header()` does *not* stop the server from processing the rest of the script. It's no different than an echo in that regard. The redirect happens client side. Think of a call to `header()` as the server shouting a command to the client. Whether or not the client obeys that command has no bearing on what the server does next.

Comment: "Let's say you had some code below that you never wanted to be executed [...]" why have it then at all? Throw it out

Comment: @MischaBehrend It's a hypothetical question of whether the code would be executed without a die and with a header :)

I know you would never put that code there without better authentication, it's a hypothetical as I explained

Answer (score 9):

`header()` appends an additional header to the output. It doesn't halt the execution of the code in the file that it is part of. Any code after a call to `header()` will still run even if it's a redirect. The browser will still redirect but the code will still be run on the server.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know, thank you for teaching me something!

Comment: Can a header mess up though? (For example not redirecting a user and then showing them a blank page)

Comment: @rakupu There is nothing to "mess up" -- the server doesn't do the redirect, the client does. The call to header is nothing more than a suggestion made from the server to the client -- the client is under no obligation to follow it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky But a user would have to disable this somehow clientside right, all browsers will follow a header regardless?

Comment: @rakupu You're erroneously assuming the client must be a browser. :)

Comment: @rakpu curl, for example, doesn't follow redirects unless you explicitly tell it to...

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use exit() or die() after any header redirection. Otherwise there is a chance unnecessary code be executed. exit() or die() ensures that the code execution is stopped in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure use exit() or die() after header function, your scenario #1 will fail

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");/* Redirect browser */
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```